# php, can't get warnings to appear on my test server, but in log file on my isps server?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the warnings to show in my php error log.
My ISP has some warnings showing and I need to be able to see them on my test server.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = "C:\php-errors.txt"
```

I've upgraded my php version too 5.2.17

I also have

```
register_globals = Off
```

Like my ISP, but I can't get any warnings to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display_errors` to `On` to display the warnings in the page (instead of in the logfile) and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` to display all warnings and errors in your `php.ini`.

Comment: @Jules If you had that, all warnings would show. Please make absolutely sure you're editing the right php.ini by creating a new file with the content <?php echo $x; phpinfo();  and checking that it 1. results in a warning 2. has the values for display_errors and error_reporting you expect.

Comment: Yes it the correct one, I've copied my phpinfo to a htm and uploaded on a different site ... http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/phpinfo.php.htm  Maybe that will help

Comment: @Jules As you can see in that phpinfo output, the settings are **not** correct: display_errors is set to *Off* instead of *On*.

Comment: No Change.... Current phpinfo http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/phpinfo.php.htm and that echo's... still not getting any warnings on the page or the error file...

Comment: @Jules if you look on the updated phpinfo output, you'll see the warnings (search for "Strict Standards"). However, it's puzzling that the first line (echo $x) does not result in an error message. Can you try introducing a "bigger" error, like *for{* or so? Also, on a completely unrelated note, you may want to update to php5.3 later.

Comment: Sorry I missed off echo $x, here it si http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/phpinfo.php.htm if I then add `for {` I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' i ... I don't want to upgrade to php php5.3 at this time

Comment: @Jules seems to work fine then, I see an error message right of the top of that page. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No My ISP is getting a warning message in his log file, lots of them. I'm not getting anything in my log file. I can't even get warnings on the web page, just notices.

Comment: @Jules I highly doubt that notices are shown, but notices are not. Please post the output of *<?php trigger_error('warning', E_WARNING);*. Also, the phpinfo example should have written a notice into C:\php-errors.log. If this is not the case, please check the permissions of that file allow the Apache process to write into it.

Comment: Ok I get this `Warning: Invalid error type specified in `, I'm not using apache I'm using IIS

Comment: @Jules well, then you are getting warnings. You wrote before: "I can't even get warnings", so something is amiss here. If you're using IIS, then check IIS' permissions for C:\php-errors.log.

Comment: Cool, do you know where I set those ?

Comment: @Jules Right click on the file in explorer -> Properties -> Security.

Answer (score 1):

ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); is a great way to change php configurations settings specific for that page only. Include it in a global header/initialization file to make it application specific. Also, as mentioned before error_reporting(E_ALL); is good for this too.

Code at the top your scripts:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Be sure to use these only for development environments only.

Comment: I have that already, I have it on both test and live servers and no warnings show, just notices. But the warnings show in the log file on the live server.

Comment: Leave error_log blank and see what happens. I said log_errors should be off earlier... leave it on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all possible warnings, try `error_reporting(-1);`, or you can put `error_reporting = -1` into the php.ini file on your test server. It works, because the internal variable is used as a bit-field, and -1 sets all the bits on, hence, showing all possible errors.

To make sure that the error_reporting is still set to what you think, the variable returns the currently set level.

```
$prevErrLevel = error_reporting(-1);
echo "errlevel was: $prevErrLevel before setting to all.", __FILE__,':',__LINE__;
```

Comment: Current phpinfo http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/phpinfo.php.htm and that echo's... errlevel was: 6143 before setting to all.... still not getting any warnings on the page or the error file...